# Is it acceptable for overloaded methods to cast their parameters and then call their original method?

Tags: c#, overloading

I wish to overload a method which currently takes a single `int` parameter.
The overloads will instead either take a `double` or a `decimal`.

Rather than the overloads casting their parameters at the top and then having the exact same code as the original, is it acceptable for them to call the original, like this?

```
int total = 0;

public void AddToTotal(int x)
{
    total += x;
}

public void AddToTotal(double x)
{
    AddToTotal((int)x);
}

public void AddToTotal(decimal x)
{
    AddToTotal((int)x);
}
```

Comment: If you don't care about losing precision then that's fine.

Comment: Yeah, @GillBates losing the precision is fine, but it's not considered poor practice or anything?

Comment: No, rather good practice since you reuse code.

Comment: There's no point in repeating the same code, yes. But why do you want those overloads in the first place? They're confusing at best, and they don't really make the code easier to read.

Comment: True @Luaan, I've decided to take the advice in the accepted answer and cast when I call the method rather than having overloads which do it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea, because you're hiding important information from the caller.
If you only expose an `int` overload, the caller can choose to cast a `double` to an `int`, knowing that it will be truncated to an integer. But if you expose an overload that takes a `double` explicitly, I would expect that `double` value to be added, not truncated.

If your method loses precision when casting, make it *explicit*, not hidden inside an overload.

Comment: I thought that OP was asking if `AddToTotal((int)x);` was a good implementation as opposed to `total += (int) x;`, but this is a good remark regardless.